# find specific string in text document with Python using a variable

Tags: python-3.x

(im a python novice)

in my python i have a shoping list which is displayed by reading an array in a text file, however when the user enters the specific product they wish to purchase i need it to lookup the products price by looking it up in the text file and therefore i need to use a variable, the problem is that when enter a product it always returns False, even if the product is in the array.

my code:

```
if FINALGTIN in open('Products.txt').read():
    VALID = True
else:
    VALID = False
```

Comment: Sorry, but if we don't know what's `FINALGTIN` nor `Products.txt` content we can't help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try stripping the product and lower-casing the strings like so

```
if FINALGTIN.strip().lower() in open('Products.txt').read().lower():
    VALID = True
else:
    VALID = False
```

Still, the better way would be to save it somewhere else and then check like so:

```
with open('Products.txt') as products_file:
    file_str = products_file.read().lower()

if FINALGTIN.strip().lower() in file_str:
    VALID = True
else:
    VALID = False
```

Comment: @Louis Can you give us an example of the input and products.txt?